# Setting spinner style cancels the onItemSelectListener setting.

Tags: android, android-spinner, listeners, event-listener

Following a previous question, and I've seen in several other questions,I setup a new costume style for my spinners on my android app. I set the spinners using

```
ArrayAdapter<String> out = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_style,toPut);
```

With `spinner_style`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
```

For the listeners, I use

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int sort, long arg3) {
                    raceChanged();

            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Which I Call from a function I call from `onCreate`. The problem is that now, when tap an item in the spinner, nothing happens. If I switch the style back to `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`. Everything works fine. How do I set my costume spinner to use the listener?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found an ugly solution. I don't know why it works, but it is. I browsed the sdk, found the `simple_spinner_item.xml` file, and copied the spinner definition to my own style and added the `textSize` line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

I would appreciate if anyone will point to the appropriate line.